# How to get child UL to come outside parent UL

Tags: html, css, html-lists

the behaviour problem explained in the title is understandable but I need a workaround.

I made an example in JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TBXr4/2/

See in the first LI I have a couple of words. They are not getting lined up like I need them to but they are getting listed. How do i resolved this?

Let me make this a little more specific, I don't want to set the width of the child UL manually, in fact I don't want one to be set. I need a way sothat the parent UL will have a width set whilst the child UL will be the smallest possible width to inherit the text.

Comment: You have a width set, and an overflow visible, what exactly do you expect from this besides what is actually happening based on those?

Comment: I need the child to go outside of the parent and not the parent resize with the child.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just set the `white-space` property of the `li` element:

```
li {
    /* other stuff */
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/TBXr4/3/).

The problem with this is that while the text will be visible outside of the parent `ul`'s assigned width, the style of the `li` (it's `background-color` / `background-image`) won't carry over.

References:

- [CSS `white-space` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/white-space).

Comment: At first I skipped the answer thinking it would cause problems with background, but using this theory, i got it to work. Thank you!

Comment: You're absolutely welcome; I'm glad to have been of some help! =)

Answer (score 1):

**[Demo is here](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/TBXr4/5/)**

i think you want this only.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the text is not displaying the sentence on one line is because you have set the width of the li, remove `style="width:35px"`.

Comment: Yeah i get that. What I'm trying to achieve is the parent width to stay the same whilst the child goes outside it.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you specifying a width to the exact element (UL) where you do not wish to adhere to it?

Apply the width setting to the main list and assign a new width to the sub-list as shown in [this jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/TBXr4/8/)